# How to show a binary string (PDF) in an embed HTML element?

Tags: vue.js, pdf, base64

I am creating a Vue component which shows PDF documents to users. Now I am getting a binary string from the backend with a content type of application/json. The response is a multipart/form-data.

Now I have an embed HTML element which I want to use for the PDF. I am using the src attribute for the data.

I have the following:

```
this.api
          .getDocument(this.documentId)
          .then((result) => {
            const base64String = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(result.data)));

            const srcString = `data:application/pdf;base64,${base64String}`;

            this.selectedBlob = srcString;
            resolve(result);
          })
```

Now I do see the built-in PDF viewer, but it shows a message that it failed to load the PDF file.

Does anyone know how to fix this?